# better method for python3 if elif else db update script

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

my code works as expected below, but I will be using this as a 'template' moving forward and before I make a giant file I wanted to make it 'cleaner' as I think I am doing it wrong even though it works.

at the top of my script can I specify the database connections and then just reference them in functions below?

```
   def db_update(x):
if x < 30:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect (host= "localhost", REDACTED)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
    cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
elif x > 270 :
    connection = MySQLdb.connect (host= "localhost", REDACTED)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
    cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
else:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect (host= "localhost", REDACTED)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
    cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

I am wondering if I could make it look like this.

```
def db_update(x):
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host= "localhost", REDACTED)
cursor = connection.cursor()
if x < 30:
    sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
elif x > 270 :
    sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
else:
    sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
cursor.fetchone()
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

or even better would be reference it from a global or an import script like so

```
def run_sql():
    connection = MySQLdb.connect (host= "localhost", REDACTED)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

def db_update(run_sql, x):
    if x < 30:
        sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
    elif x > 270 :
        sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
    else:
        sqlcommand = """REDACTED"""
    runsql()
```

I am *very* new to this so please be gentle and if there are good learning links please feel free to share

Comment: Does your second set of code work as expected? Please try running it and report if it causes any problems.

Comment: it does work, wow. I feel quite a bit silly at the moment.
as a followup, is there a way to make the db connection a global object so I do not have to put any of it or much of it in any functions?

Comment: In general, if I find myself typing code more than once, there's probably a way to simplify or abstract it.

Comment: @username: You _can_ make things global, but you should prefer making them be function parameters (and/or return values).  If you get a lot of such parameters that always appear together in a function signature, you can make a class to hold them as members and make the functions methods on it.